# How can I make different textures on the same object?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to make a circle in which there will be a smaller circle at same origin point. I will use circle mesh for both these circles. I will put the image texture for the bigger circle. I just want to make the edge of the inner circle in a different color. How can I achieve that?

I want my model to look like this. A small circle inside a big circle with only the edge of the inner circle showing.

[image: Circle in circle]

Comment: Hi, Please give more details on what you need. Do you need help just with the edge being a different colour, the materials, adding the circles or everything? And are you working in Blender Internal or Cycles?

Comment: related:  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Hi VolkEnVaderland, Thanks for your reply. I am using the Blender Internal engine. I have edited my original question and added png image to show you how my model must look like

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all using only one mesh and procedural materials, even using the blender internal render.

1. Add a material, then go to the texture tab of the properties window.
2. Add a new "*Blend*" texture.
3. Down in the "*Blend*" section, set the "*Progression*" to "*Spherical*".
4. Set the texture coordinates to "*Generated*".
5. (Now the fun part) Go back up to the "*Color*" section and check the checkbox for "*Ramp*". Set the interpolation to "*Constant*"
   First make sure that you set the alpha of the first color stop to `1` (By default it is zero).
   [image: alpha set to one]
   Now we are ready to add new color stops in the color ramp.
   As shown in the image below you will need one stop placed at `0` (the far left) then two more color stops. These next two color stops make the ring.

[image: texture settings]

---

### Using two meshes

If you want to use two separate meshes (can be in the same object or separate objects), then you need nothing more then a simple material on each part.
[image: circle made with two meshes]
Here I applied a purple material to a basic circle. In the same spot (just slightly higher)  I have a smaller circle. This circle I extruded <kbd>E</kbd>, then scaled <kbd>S</kbd> so that it is just a thin rim (green in the picture). I then applied a green material to this mesh.

If you have both of these pieces in the same object, then you will have to apply the material in edit mode as explained in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/2217).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use different textures on the same object, by assigning the textures to different materials. The two materials can be identical (except for the name, and the texture assigned to the material), in the case of the example provided by the original poster, the outer circle would be assigned a material with an image texture applied, while the inner circle would be assigned a material with a different texture (for the purposes of this answer, no texture is a texture) applied. Note, though, that the outer ring of the inner circle must consist of faces; materials (and therefore textures) do not show on an edge.